# ¿Cómo utilizar el boolean en lectura Scanner?

Tags: java

¡Hola! Me encuentro realizndo un ejercicio y no comprendo como definir el boolen en Java, en pseint era más sencillo... Pero aquí creo que me estoy confundiendo. ¿Cómo podría leer el si o no?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner lectura = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int num;
    boolean opc;
    double pago, suma;
    
    suma=0;
    
    while(opc=true){
        System.out.println("Ingresar la cantidd de menús a cancelr");
        num = lectura.nextInt();
        
        pago = num *7.5;
        
        System.out.println("El cliente debe pagar: "+pago+" soles");
        
        suma = suma + pago;
        
        System.out.println("¿Desea registrar otro consumo?"+
                                        "\nSi = 1 o No= 2");
        opc = lectura.nextBoolean();
    }
    
    System.out.println("El total recauddo por el restataurante es: "+suma+" soles");
}
```

Comment: En realidad lo que quieres leer es 1 o 2, y `1` y `2` no son booleanos, son un enteros, por tanto, usarías nextInt. Te recomiendo declarar `opc` como entero e inicializarlo en `1`. Te adjunto [un ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/2TNgAk4v4).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ¡Muchisimas gracias!